# Copying and selection of ranges of non-contiguous rows

Tags: excel, vba, select, range

Trying to select non-contiguous rows in excel, and then copy them to another application.

When I copy the range it comes up as:

```
Range("A1:1,A4:D4,A6:D7").Select
Range("A6").Activate
```

However, when I copy the cells from this selected range it copies the equivalent of:

```
Range("A1:D7").Select
```

Is there anyway to avoid the selection/copying of the rows between the selected rows?

Comment: That would work in Excel, but not when pasting into another application. I'm guessing you'd have to populate the clipboard "manually" if you wanted to exclude the non-selected cells

Comment: @TimWilliams Do you think it would work if my macro copied the values to a temporary worksheet then selected + copied these values from the temporary worksheet before closing?

Comment: That might well be fine - should be easy to test.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to avoid the selection/copying of the rows between the
>   selected rows?

You can try to use range array .. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx